# How do I read data from a txt file? It is a matrix with unknown dimensions, first lines are text (timestamp actually and the names of the variables)

Tags: matrix, octave

In Matlab, I use readmatrix which apparently does not work in octave.

The file may look like this:

```
# timestamp 1627575141.861
# time[s], current[A]
0.000 0.407
0.285 0.407
0.563 0.408
0.841 0.407
etc.
```

or:

```
# timestamp 1627575273.9524
# time_1[s], integ_1, raw_1, time_2[s], integ_2, raw_2, time_3[s], integ_3, raw_3, time_4[s], integ_4, raw_4, time_5[s], integ_5, raw_5, time_6[s], integ_6, raw_6, time_7[s], integ_7, raw_7, time_8[s], integ_8, raw_8, time_9[s], integ_9, raw_9
0.0286 2.5153 2.5263 0.0555 2.5519 2.5226 0.0289 2.4860 2.5079 0.0290 2.5018 2.4750 0.0206 2.5482 2.5006 0.0294 2.5067 2.4860 0.0298 2.4884 2.4969 0.0204 2.5226 2.4896 0.0302 2.3919 2.5055
0.0485 2.5116 2.5079 0.0754 2.5507 2.5165 0.0488 2.4811 2.4896 0.0489 2.5092 2.5067 0.0404 2.5433 2.4811 0.0493 2.5104 2.4982 0.0496 2.4884 2.4860 0.0403 2.5238 2.4969 0.0500 2.3907 2.4921
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the numeric data you should use `dlmread`:

```matlab
data = dlmread('filename', ' ', 2, 0);
```

`' '` says that the numbers are separated by spaces.

`2` is the number of rows to skip before reading numeric data. It is the number of header lines in your files.

Similarly, `0` is the number of columns to skip.

---

If you need the data in header lines, you need to parse them yourself. This is one way of doing it:

```matlab
f = fopen('filename');
fscanf(f, '# ');        % skip '# '
line1 = fgetl(f);       % read the rest of the line
fscanf(f, '# ');        % skip '# '
line2 = fgetl(f);       % read the rest of the line
fclose(f);

timestamp = sscanf(line1, 'timestamp %f'); % read timestamp as a number
variableNames = strsplit(line2, {', '});   % split the words in line2 separated by ', '
```